# Эффективный многопоточный поиск по строковым полям

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции

В систему загружается полумиллионный список объектов `User`. Каждый объект содержит уникальный `id` и произвольные строковые `name` и `email`. Мне нужно найти все `User`, поля которых содержат подстроку `substring`. При этом выходной список должен быть упорядочен по `id`.
Вопрос в следующем: какую коллекцию стоит использовать и как организовать наиболее эффективный перебор всех строковых полей? Стоит ли упорядочивать коллекцию после поиска или же делать это при загрузке?

Comment: Что вы используете в качестве базы данных?

Comment: @AK, база данных тут не используется. Список элементов может генерироваться, а может загружаться из файла. Главное, что на вход поступают данные и мне периодически нужно делать по ним поиск.

Comment: Если речь идет о быстром поиске по подстроке, то префиксное дерево - ваш вариант. Вы получите линейное время на поиск и линейно-логаричмическое на сортировку (если будете сортировать айдишники подсчетом, то это вообще может в сортировку за линейной время превратиться). Только памяти это будет кушать довольно много :)

Comment: Для начала я бы попробовал PLINQ

Comment: [Pattern Searching using a Trie of all Suffixes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-using-trie-suffixes/)

Comment: @АндрейNOP я думал автору надо эффективный многопоточный, а не просто многопоточный :)

Comment: @tym32167, ну многопоточность даст PLINQ, для эффективного поиска подстроки можно реализовать КМП-алгоритм. А сортировка и так O(n log n)

Comment: @АндрейNOP это да, но если реализовать суффиксное дерево для всех подстрок + хранить юзеров уже отсортированными, то вся операция будет за константу (точнее линойно от длины подстроки) :)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо. А не подскажете префиксное или суффиксное дерево все-таки использовать? Есть ли какие-то реализации в .NET?

Comment: Суффиксное, я пример скинул, там пример на Java, но на C# будет оч похоже.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, получается нужно последовательно к каждому полю класса User применять КМП-алгоритм? А как это скрестить с PLINQ?

Comment: `.AsParallel().Where(u => KMPContains(u.Name, pattern) || KMPContains(u.Email, pattern)).OrderBy(u => u.Id)` либо использовать `AsOrdered`, если данные уже поступают отсортированными